# controlling program flow without if-else / switch-case statements

Tags: function, programming-languages, function-pointers, program-flow

Let's say I have 1000 functions defined as follows

```
void func dummy1(int a);
void func dummy2(int a, int aa);
void func dummy3(int a, int aa, int aaa);
.
.
.
void func dummy1000(int a, int aa, int aaa, ...);
```

I want to write a function that takes an integer, n (n < 1000) and calls nth dummy function (in case of 10, dummy10) with exactly n arguments(arguments can be any integer, let's say 0) as required. I know this can be achieved by writing a switch case statement with 1000 cases which is not plausible.

In my opinion, this cannot be achieved without recompilation at run time so languages like java, c, c++ will never let such a thing happen.

Hopefully, there is a way to do this. If so I am curious.

Note: This is not something that I will ever use, I asked question just because of my curiosity.

Comment: Have you looked at reflection before?

Comment: Is the "n args" part of it incidental, or is that the example you wish to find a solution for? If so, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h

Comment: "N args" part is not incidental, I included that in question on purpose. I have checked that library now, however I think it doesn't help if you want your functions to have certain number of arguments but calling them without using control statements.

Comment: A very short shell script would generate the thousand-headed case statement you seem to despair of.

Comment: Yes, no doubt it would

Comment: You should look at [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern functional languages, you can make a list of functions which take a list as an argument.  This will arguably solve your problem, but it is also arguably cheating, as it is not quite the statically-typed implementation your question seems to imply.  However, it is pretty much what dynamic languages such as Python, Ruby, or Perl do when using "manual" argument handling...

Anyway, the following is in Haskell:  it supplies the `n`th function (from its first argument `fs`) a list of `n` copies of the second argument (`x`), and returns the result.  Of course, you will need to put together the list of functions somehow, but unlike a switch statement this list will be reusable as a first-class argument.

```
selectApplyFunction :: [ [Int] -> a ] -> Int -> Int -> a
selectApplyFunction fs x n = (fs !! (n-1)) (replicate n x)

dummy1 [a] = 5 * a
dummy2 [a, b] = (a + 3) * b
dummy3 [a, b, c] = (a*b*c) / (a*b + b*c + c*a)
...
myFunctionList = [ dummy1, dummy2, dummy3, ... ]

-- (myfunction n) provides n copies of the number 42 to the n'th function
myFunction = selectApplyFunction myFunctionList 42

-- call the 666'th function with 666 copies of 42
result = myFunction 666
```

Of course, you will get an exception if `n` is greater than the number of functions, or if the function can't handle the list it is given.  Note, too, that it is poor Haskell style -- mainly because of the way it abuses lists to (abusively) solve your problem...

Comment: No doubt interpreted languages will do this job somehow since they have a chance to interpret input before execution as in this example. I just wondered if that is also possible with a language doesn't have a way to interpret run time input.

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding:  Haskell is a statically-typed language, whose dominant implementation (GHC) is a compiler.  Compiled languages and interpreted languages are equally capable of interpreting runtime input.

Comment: My minor point was that my Haskell solution was doing "by hand" (with statically-typed lists) what dynamic languages implement implicitly (as part of their argument-handling mechanics).  My major point was that my solution may have answered the question asked, but probably didn't properly satisfy your curiosity -- so, you probably need to do some more thinking, and some more studying, and come up with a better question 8^)

Comment: Compiler should know the number of arguments exactly so it can generate instructions for pushing arguments onto stack before calling the function. When which function to call and so directly number of arguments needed depend on an input from user, code should be written with flow control instructions which results in a number of jump instructions in assembly. However, in an interpreted language, interpreter can interpret the command just at the time of execution to generate 'some new instructions' in this case you don't need any control flow statements in source code just as in your example.

Comment: No my question was originally how this could be achieved without any dynamic recompilation just like how reflection and your solution do, I am not satisfied.

Comment: Nonetheless, Haskell compilers typically do not do dynamic compilation, and should compile this example just fine.  Note that you could do the same thing in C++, by using dynamic dispatch.

Comment: hmm, I think now I got it. GHC seems to need generating many jump instructions in assembly even though there is no one single if statement in your code. Maybe how a function call is realized in computer architecture so corresponds to how we write code to call functions in C made me think there is no way to achieve this without 'recompilation' and control statements. Apparently, there is. What you said your minor point answers my question thanks!

Comment: Would Haskell do this job if arguments of functions were of different types? I think no because of in that case statically-typed lists couldn't work

Comment: Correct.  To pull the same trick you'd need to fake up some kind of union type, which included all argument types the function list might use...

Answer (score 0):

No, you are incorrect. Most modern languages support some form of Reflection that will allow you to call a function by name and pass params to it.

Comment: Will reflection allow me to pass parameters from a string which can be initialized and assigned at run-time?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of functions in most of modern languages.
In pseudo code,

```
var dummy = new Array();
dummy[1] = function(int a);
dummy[2] = function(int a, int aa);
...

var result = dummy[whateveryoucall](1,2,3,...,whateveryoucall);
```

Comment: How does this solution deal with different number of parameters of functions?

Answer (score 0):

In functional languages you could do something like this, in strongly typed ones, like Haskell, the functions must have the same type, though:

```
funs = [reverse, tail, init]   -- 3 functions of type [a]->[a]

run fn arg = (funs !! fn) $ args  -- applies function at index fn to args
```

Answer (score 0):

In object oriented languages, you can use [function objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object) and reflection together to achieve exactly what you want. The problem of the variable number of arguments is solved by passing appropriate POJOs (recalling C stucts) to the function object.

```
interface Functor<A,B> {
    public B compute(A input);
}

class SumInput {
    private int x, y;
    // getters and setters
}

class Sum implements Functor<SumInput, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer compute(SumInput input) {
       return input.getX() + input.getY();
    }

}
```

Now imagine you have a large number of these "functors". You gather them in a configuration file (maybe an XML file with metadata about each functor, usage scenarios, instructions, etc...) and return the list to the user.
The user picks one of them. By using reflection, you can see what is the required input and the expected output. The user fills in the input, and by using reflection you instantiate the functor class (`newInstance()`), call the `compute()` function and get the output.
When you add a new functor, you just have to change the list of the functors in the config file.